# Read collection with documents of varying schema from mongo using spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a collection with documents of varying schema from mongo using spark-mongo connector to get a dataframe. What is see is that spark is inferring the schema for the dataframe from the first record and if i query the dataframe for any other field , i am getting an excpetion. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Which connector? The official one (https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector) ? It will sample the data based on the sample size set in the configs. Can you include the schema (`df.printSchema()`) and an example of the operation on the dataframe.

Comment: Yes, this one only. The issue is that each document in the collection has different schema. So, what happens in that case? Can you please elaborate a little on what do you mean by sample size set in config. Where i can find documentation related to that.  Also, are you gyus are planning support for spark-2.0 , as i was not able to make ti work with that.

Comment: Don't use DataFrames if all documents have a different schema, use RDD's.  There is an release candidate out for Spark 2.0 on maven central.

Comment: Okk, Thanks a lot :)